# issue with npm run watch

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, package.json

I am working on a vue.js project. When I am trying to run `npm run watch` I am getting below error.

[image]

Here is my composer.json file code

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Read https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Answer (score 1):

As you have not added watch scripts in the package.json npm run watch won't work.

you can use
npm run scripts-name , or any of the start/developer/build in place of scripts-name

or  you can add watch in scripts tag and use it.

Comment: Thanks @rav for your reply. How can I add watch scripts in scripts tag in the package.json ? Could you please show me some examples ? Thanks.

Comment: you can add "watch":"command which you want to run", to scripts

Comment: Thanks @rav. Actually I would like to have auto execution of code while I change in my code. That's why I would like to run `npm run watch`.

Comment: as you want to auto execute the code , you can use nodemon npm module ,what is does is whenever the code changes it will compile and build,and those changes will be reflected on the go.